# Python ObjectListView add animation when the list is empty

Tags: python, objectlistview

Right now, I am writing a python program using ObjectListView package. When the list is empty, the back ground will show words "This list is empty". But I want to change it into an animation. How to realize it?
Do I have to change the ObjectListView library to realize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This list is empty" is shown in a `StaticText` control (named `stEmptyListMsg`). You can change the message and the font by calling `SetEmptyListMsg` and `SetEmptyListMsgFont` respectively.

If you want to replace the `StaticText` with an animation, then, I think, you should write your own custom `ListCtrl` based on `ObjectListView` or `ListCtrl`.

This link can help you to create an animation: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/216673/wxpython-animated-gif#